# mvc3 strip html attributes from textbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a forum which has a rich text editor to allow some Html on posting. I have a 2nd textbox that i would like to use for copying whatever content is inside the rich text editor but this time stripping out all html attributes for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult posting(string post,thread newthread)
{
     //The post string has the Html in it from the text editor
     newthread.post = post;
     newthread.Nohtml= post;
     //The problem is above how can I strip out all HTML elements and save it in Nohtml
     db.threads.Add(newthread);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see from the above code the **post** has HTML, but I want to strip the HTML when saving it into the **Nohtml** that way I can show previews of the thread question, in what way can I accomplish this?

Comment: Find a library for stripping HTML or write some code to strip the HTML. There are plenty of resources (and other SO questions) that can help you with this. Try searching.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that might have this issue I have found the solution

```
 newthread.Nohtml = Regex.Replace(post, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```